# how to view and edit meta tags in python programming

Tags: python, tags, id3

I have used other programming languages like java to edit meta tags but every time i am only able to edit the number in the genre tag.

I have seen in  many soft wares like media monkey enables us to edit the genre tag with the name we want.

Currently, genre tag only allows to write numbers from 1 to 79 but not the strings.

Example code :

```
from ID3 import *
    try:
      id3info = ID3('/some/file/moxy.mp3')
      print id3info
      id3info['TITLE'] = "Green Eggs and Ham"
      id3info['ARTIST'] = "Moxy Früvous"
          for k, v in id3info.items():
            print k, ":", v
        except InvalidTagError, message:
          print "Invalid ID3 tag:", message
```

How can i edit the genre tag with the string i want in python ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like ID3 defines genre to be an integer, [mappable to a genre](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Appendix_A_-_Genre_List_from_ID3v1) -- You might inspect an mp3 that has a string genre to see where they're storing it.

Comment: What ID3 package are you using?

Comment: I just tried it with pytagger (link to package in my answer) and was able to set the genre to an arbitrary string.  pytagger is pure python, so you should be able to install it on any OS without having to compile anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID3v1 only supports one byte numeric values for genre.

ID3v2 has [broader support for metadata](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Text_information_frames).  In ID3v2, you can set a TCON frame with your genre string.

For example, using the [pytagger](http://www.liquidx.net/pytagger/) package:

```
import tagger

id3 = tagger.ID3v2(r'whatever.mp3')

tagged = False
# Try to find a TCON frame to replace the contents
for frame in id3.frames:
    if frame.fid == 'TCON':
        frame.set_text('Blues')
        tagged = True
# There were no TCON frames, add one
if not tagged:
    genre = id3.new_frame('TCON')
    genre.set_text('Blues')
    id3.frames.append(genre)

id3.commit()
```